# java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0

Tags: android, android-tablelayout

I am getting a `java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0` error with this code and I'm not sure to why I'm receiving it. I'm trying to fill a table layout with dynamic data that I receive from a xml string.

```
public void createTable(String xmlForTable) 
    throws XmlPullParserException, IOException {
//public void createTable(){

    Integer rowCount = 0;
    endPlacementTag = "nothing";
    //setContentView(R.layout.activity_all_tires);

     lo = (TableLayout)  findViewById(R.id.tiresTable);

     TableRow headerRow = new TableRow(this);
     TableRow.LayoutParams hp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
     headerRow.setLayoutParams(hp);

     tv = new TextView(this);
     tv.setText("Text Header");
     headerRow.addView(tv);
     //lo.addView(headerRow);

     XmlPullParserFactory factory = XmlPullParserFactory.newInstance();
     factory.setNamespaceAware(true);
     XmlPullParser xpp = factory.newPullParser();

     xpp.setInput(new StringReader (xmlForTable));
     int eventType = xpp.getEventType();

     TableRow row= new TableRow(this);
        TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,TableRow.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT);
        row.setLayoutParams(lp);

       ...
        materialNumber = new TextView(this);


     for(int i=0; i < xmlForTable.length(); i ++){

        if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("Start document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_DOCUMENT) {

              System.out.println("End document");

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.START_TAG) {

              System.out.println("Start tag "+xpp.getName());
              placementTag = xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.END_TAG) {

              System.out.println("End tag "+xpp.getName());
              endPlacementTag = "End tag "+xpp.getName();

          } else if(eventType == XmlPullParser.TEXT) {

              System.out.println("Text "+xpp.getText());
           if(placementTag.equals("MaterialNumber"))
              {
                  materialNumber.setText(xpp.getText());
                  materialNumber.setTextSize(10);                   
                  materialNumber.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams (LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT));
                  /*row.addView(materialNumber);
                  row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                  row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));*/
                  placementTag = "";

              }
              else if(endPlacementTag.equals("End tag Table")) 
              {

                  ...//other row.adds
                  row.addView(materialNumber);

                  row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
                  row.setLayoutParams(new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

                  //lo.addView(row, i, new TableLayout.LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT,LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
                  lo.addView(row, rowCount);

                  rowCount++;
                  //i++;
                  row.removeAllViews();
                  lo.removeAllViews();

              }

              }
          eventType = xpp.next();
          }
```

LogCat:

```
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: index=1 count=0
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addInArray(ViewGroup.java:3653)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addViewInner(ViewGroup.java:3584)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3415)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:429)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.view.ViewGroup.addView(ViewGroup.java:3360)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.widget.TableLayout.addView(TableLayout.java:411)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity.createTable(AllTiresActivity.java:384)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at cooper.tirerfid.AllTiresActivity$1.run(AllTiresActivity.java:483)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:733)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5017)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:779)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:595)
08-06 11:24:00.210: E/AndroidRuntime(2979):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

I had the program working so that it didnt error out, however the data table would still not fill up with data it would just be blank so I switched it around and now it just crashes on me when I go to run it so I'm stuck...again...

Comment: your trying to get row contains data from array with zero rows

Comment: eventType = xpp.next(); //comment this line.

Comment: @MhmdAljobairi what do you mean check my request?

Comment: I mean like what does that mean?

Comment: I have the same problem with my code....give me solution if you got..

Answer (score 0):

You are adding the subviews in if loop, so you can avoid to give position as a second parameter, it is optional. 
     lo.addView(row, rowCount);

replace to:
     lo.addView(row);

Android will take care of row count.